# Parsing screen data

Tags: c, parsing, arrays, stm32f4discovery

I am trying to develop my own USB DisplayLink device for Linux. My device comunicates and I constantly receive screen data. My problem is when i received green screen, data on LCD display are totally mixed. I know the structure of commands:

[image]

Translation of labels:

1. Identificator of command
2. Address
3. Total count of pixels in this command ( 0 == 256)
4. Count of next byte pairs ( contains color )
5. Representation of pixel which is not repeated on line
6. Representation of pixel which is repeated on line
7. Number of repeats the pixel which is previous

Code is:

```
    static int const newWidth = 320;
static int const newHeight = 240;
static int const width = 800;
static int const height = 600;

int* svga;
int* qvga;

static uint32_t ShortToLong(uint16_t color)
{
    uint32_t r = (color & 0xF800) >>11;
    uint32_t g = (color & 0x07E0) >>5;
    uint32_t b = (color & 0x001F);

    r = r * 255 / 31;
    g = g * 255 / 63;
    b = b * 255 / 31;

    return ((255 << 24) |(r << 16) | (g << 8) | b);
}

static void Resample()
{
    double scaleWidth = (double)newWidth / (double)width;
    double scaleHeight = (double)newHeight / (double)height;

    int cy;
    int cx;

    for (cy = 0; cy < newHeight; cy++)
    {
        for (cx = 0; cx < newWidth; cx++)
        {
            int nearestMatch = (((int)(cy / scaleHeight) * (width)) + ((int)(cx / scaleWidth)));
            BSP_LCD_DrawPixel(cy, cx, svga[nearestMatch]);
        }
    }
}

static int8_t CDC_Init_HS(void)
{
  hUsbDevice_1 = &hUsbDeviceHS;
  /* Set Application Buffers */
  USBD_CDC_SetTxBuffer(hUsbDevice_1, UserTxBufferHS, 0);
  USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer(hUsbDevice_1, UserRxBufferHS);
  USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(hUsbDevice_1);

  svga = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 800 * 600);
  qvga = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 320 * 240);

  return (USBD_OK);
}


static int8_t CDC_Receive_HS (uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t *Len)
{
    uint32_t readIndex = 0;
    if (Buf[readIndex] == 175 && Buf[readIndex+1] == 107)
    {
        while (readIndex < *Len)
        {
            if (Buf[readIndex] == 175 && Buf[readIndex+1] == 107)
            {
                uint32_t address;
                int currentPixelValue;
                int repeatCount;

                readIndex += 2;

                address = ((Buf[readIndex++] << 16) & 0xFF);//read address (start at 0 end at 256 in case of 256 pixels)
                address += ((Buf[readIndex++] << 8) & 0xFF);
                address += (Buf[readIndex++] & 0xFF);

                int totalPixelCount = Buf[readIndex++] & 0xFF; // read count of all pixels in this command (256 == 0) 
                int rawPixelCount = Buf[readIndex++] + 1; // read count of pixels to read (byte tuples)

                while (rawPixelCount > 0) // process current number of byte tuples
                {
                    currentPixelValue = (Buf[readIndex++] << 8);
                    currentPixelValue += Buf[readIndex++];
                    uint32_t color = ShortToLong(currentPixelValue);
                    svga[address] = color;
                    address++;
                    rawPixelCount -= 2;
                    if (rawPixelCount == 0)
                    {
                        repeatCount = Buf[readIndex++];
                        while (repeatCount >= 0)
                        {
                            svga[address] = color;
                            address++;
                            repeatCount--;
                        }
                        rawPixelCount = Buf[readIndex++]; //read count of next bytes for reading
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        Resample();
    }
    USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(hUsbDevice_1);
    return (USBD_OK);
}
```

Resampling from 800×600 to 320×240 is done because DL lowest resoultion is 800×600 and I have LCD with resolution 320×240.

I think that mistake is somewhere in CDC_Receive_HS method but i cant figure out where.

Input data are e.q.:

```
0000   af 6b 00 00 00 00 01 37 e6 ff 00 af 6b 00 02 00
0010   00 01 37 e6 ff 00 af 6b 00 04 00 00 01 37 e6 ff
0020   00 af 6b 00 06 00 20 01 37 e6 1f 00 af 6b 00 06
0030   40 00 01 37 e6 ff 00 af 6b 00 08 40 00 01 37 e6
0040   ff 00 af 6b 00 0a 40 00 01 37 e6 ff 00 af 6b 00
0050   0c 40 20 01 37 e6 1f 00 af 6b 00 0c 80 00 01 37
0060   e6 ff 00 af 6b 00 0e 80 00 01 37 e6 ff 00 af 6b
0070   00 10 80 00 01 37 e6 ff 00 af 6b 00 12 80 20 01
0080   37 e6 1f 00 af 6b 00 12 c0 00 01 37 e6 ff 00 af
0090   6b 00 14 c0 00 01 37 e6 ff 00 af 6b 00 16 c0 00
00a0   01 37 e6 ff 00 af 6b 00 18 c0 20 01 37 e6 1f 00
00b0   af 6b 00 19 00 00 01 37 e6 ff 00 af 6b 00 1b 00
00c0   00 01 37 e6 ff 00 af 6b 00 1d 00 00 01 37 e6 ff
00d0   00 af 6b 00 1f 00 20 01 37 e6 1f 00 af 6b 00 1f
00e0   40 00 01 37 e6 ff 00 af 6b 00 21 40 00 01 37 e6
00f0   ff 00 af 6b 00 23 40 00 01 37 e6 ff 00 af 6b 00
0100   25 40 20 01 37 e6 1f 00 af 6b 00 25 80 00 01 37
0110   e6 ff 00 .....
```

Output on LCD looks like this:

[image]

Thanks for any help.